# Classifying groups of order 56 (partial)

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

This is a long problem in Dummit & Foote, for which I have some pieces and others are covered elsewhere here. In general, I tend to struggle when the "K" group is a direct product. Here's my way of trying to see it for the case when K = $Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} = <a> \times <b> \times <c>$, and we're looking at homomorphisms from here into Aut$(Z_{7}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Using the First Isomorphism Theorem combined with Lagrange's Theorem, I know the image of any such $\phi$ must have order either 1 or 2, which forces its kernel to be of order either 8 or 4 respectively. Thus, in order to find all non-trivial homomorphisms, we find all subgroups of $Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2}$ with order 4 and identify each one with a $\phi_{i}$.

There are seven total of these. Because I know there's only one semi-direct product when $K$ is in this form, I know all seven of the corresponding homomorphisms are going to induce isomorphic groups. I can prove this by showing all the kernels are isomorphic. But this seems tedious to check. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Here's the key: your $K$ is completely reducible. This means every subgroup has a complement (just see $K$ as a vector space). So if $\phi$ has order 2, let $H$ be the order 4 kernel in $K$. There is a subgroup $L$ of order 2 in $K$ such that $K=HL$. Then the generator of $L$ maps to $\phi$. What this all means is that you only have to consider the case where $a$ and $b$ are in the kernel, and $c$ acts non-trivially.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that last line? Also, I prefer the notation (a, 1, 1) in the kernel just because it reminds me literally what I'm working with.

Comment: The "change of basis" I described is really an automorphism of your $K$. Generally, if $\psi:\ K\rightarrow Aut(N)$ defines a semidirect product $G_1=K\ltimes N$, and $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $K$, then we can also define a semidirect product using $\psi\alpha:\ K\rightarrow Aut(N)$, call it $G_2$. Then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, with an explicit isomorphism $(k,n)\mapsto(\alpha^{-1}(k), n)$.